# Check list elements for a login system from another class java

Tags: java, list, methods

So i have 2 classes(client and server) and im coding a login system. A list of valid usernames is stored at the server class.
I need the client to check if data are valid using a server's class method that holds usernames . How i can retrieve that data from the list.

I want to do something like this:

Client class

```
      server sr = new server();
      System.out.println("username: ");    
      logUsername = inl.readLine();
      System.out.println("password: ");
      logPassword = inl.readLine();
      //i cant code this if statement to retrive usernames from list
      if (sr.list(usernames).equals(logUsername))
      {
        ...some code
      }
```

Server class

```
      List<String> list()
      {
           List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
           usernames.add("user1");
           usernames.add("user2");
           usernames.add("user3");
           return usernames;     
    }
```

Do I have to change the method "String" to "void" or what? I'm confused

Comment: You want to return a `List<String>` which is called `usernames` so your return type should also be `List<String>`

Comment: @Mark Also, he compares the list to `logUsername`, which is a single string, and will never resolve to true. It needs to be `sr.list(usernames).contains(logUsername)`

Comment: my fault, i edited it

Comment: Your method doesn't have a name... This is basic syntax

Comment: @Michael sounds good but i get a red line at my if statements for the word "usernames". It says cannot find symbol "usernames" in class client.. But its located to the server using server sr = new server();

Answer (score 2):

In the server class you should return `List<String>`

```
List<String> list() {
    List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
    usernames.add("user1");
    usernames.add("user2");
    usernames.add("user3");
    return usernames;     
}
```

Then in your client class call this method to fetch the user list

```
List<String> alluser = se.list();
```

Now check this list with your user provided name

```
if (alluser.contains(loginUsername)) {
     .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the return type to `List<String>`, and you need to change the `if` to check if the username is in the list using `contains`, not `equals`. In addition, initialize the list once in the constructor, not every time you are getting the list

```
public class Server {

    private List<String> usernames;

    public Server() {
        this.usernames = new ArrayList<>();
        this.usernames.add("user1");
        this.usernames.add("user2");
        this.usernames.add("user3");
    }

    public List<String> getUsernames() {
        return this.usernames;     
    }
}

Server sr = new Server();
if (sr.getUsernames().contains(logUsername)) {
    // some code
}
```

*Note: classes in Java start with uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be like

```
public List<String> list()
     {
          List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
          usernames.add("user1");
          usernames.add("user2");
          usernames.add("user3");
          return usernames;     
   }
```

and in your Client class you should write if condition like

```
if(sr.list().contains(logUsername)) {
Your logic here...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Server method to :

```
public List<String> getList() {
       List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
       usernames.add("user1");
       usernames.add("user2");
       usernames.add("user3");
       return usernames;     
}
```

and change the validation to this:

```
if (sr.getList().contains(logUsername)){
    // This code is executed when the list contains the matching UserName.
}
```

There are a few things you should have a look at: the contains(String) will work Case-sensitive so -> "user1" != "User1"

Validating the Users on a client side seems to be very wrong for me... (Security)